# How can this post have nothing in it, no chars at all when opening the edit box?

Tags: discussion, posting

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476739/3956566). It's been deleted.
So here is a screenshot:

[image]

And this is when opening the edit box:

[image]

There is nothing there.

Its revision history after being deleted;

[image]

How is this possible? Is this a bug?

*I'm on the latest Chrome browser on Windows.*

Comment: When I opened the edit box for that post, there seemed to be quite a few characters which were not recognised by my browser. Strange. (FF latest version, windows 10)

Comment: @angussidney ah, just updated my post with my browser and pc. interesting

Comment: It has a tonne of non-printable characters in it.  I saw them by viewing the page source.  See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mMiJ.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities for how this answer was constructed. (And it is most likely not a bug.) The most likely is 30[+] invisible characters. Some examples of invisible characters are:

`͏
COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER
Unicode: U+034F, UTF-8: CD 8F`

`‍
ZERO WIDTH JOINER
Unicode: U+200D, UTF-8: E2 80 8D`

`‭
LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE
Unicode: U+202D, UTF-8: E2 80 AD`

`MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN BEAM
Unicode: U+1D173, UTF-8: F0 9D 85 B3`

`MUSICAL SYMBOL END BEAM
Unicode: U+1D174, UTF-8: F0 9D 85 B4`